# How to use querySelector when manipulating elements with classes that contain multiple words?

Tags: addeventlistener, queryselector

I'm trying to addEventListener that will listen for "click"s and will return an alert.
Is it class name or something else that creates the problem?
Couldn't figure out what am I doing wrong in this code:

```
HTML:
<button class="w drum">w</button>


Javascript:
var wDrum = document.querySelector(".w drum");
wDrum.addEventListener('click', 'alert("click!")');
```

Answer (score 0):

All you're missing is changing the selector to `.w.drum` to find both classes on the same element:

```js
var wDrum = document.querySelector(".w.drum");
```

Comment: That was a point that had to be changed to get result, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving you hint how to make workaround.

@pavlindrom answer is the shortest way to go around and should be a way to go.

But suppose you don't want to go around with `'.w.drum'` then my friend you need to get learned about [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value_contains.asp)

Among many ways [attribute=value] is a way to target class attribute on the button. This is probabaly what query selector is doing behind the scene for `'.w.drum'`.

So in our case it would become `"[class*=w drum]"`. `'*='` part means constains substring in given string.

**Example with attribute searching : side note will throw error.**

```js
var wDrum = document.querySelector("[class*=w drum]");

wDrum.addEventListener('click', () => {alert("click!")})
```

```html
<button class="w drum">w</button>
```

Error is genrated becuase of space between **w drum** in `[class*=w drum]` JS engine doesn't really try too hard to make sense of things on its own.

So we have to tell it by explicitly telling it what mean, by using quotes. thus `"[class*=w drum]"` becomes `"[class*='w drum']"`

**Updated Example: it works**

```js
var wDrum = document.querySelector("[class*='w drum']");

wDrum.addEventListener('click', () => {alert("click!")})
```

```html
<button class="w drum">w</button>
```

If you keep the order of words right, it can work fine.

```js
var wDrum = document.querySelector("[class*='w drum']");

wDrum.addEventListener('click', () => {alert("click!")})
```

```html
<button class=" another-class w drum some-other-class">w</button>
```

**Explainer in connection with your comment**

**.class1 .class2** With space in between classes selects all elements i.e. class 2 that are descendant of an element with class1

For example;

```
<div class='class1'>
<span class='class2'></span>
</div>
```

**.class1.class2**  with out any space searches for all elements with both class1 and class2 set within its class attribute

For example;

```
<div class='class1 class2'>
<span class='class2'></span>
</div>
```

document.querySelector(".w.drum") would return **div** tag because both classes are present in same tag attribute.

Why did the arrow function work?

`addEventListener` function expects two arguments ie.

```
.addEventListener(argument1, argument2)
```

- `argument1` must be a string referencing particular event type.
- `argument2` must be a call back function or at least reference to a already declared function.

For example

```
.addEventListener('click', function_name)
```

or as in direct declaration of function

```
.addEventListener('click', function () {})
```

or as in arrow function

```
.addEventListener('click', () => {})
```

Your code had argument2 as string so it didn't work

```
wDrum.addEventListener('click', 'alert("click!")')
```

but if we change it to function it works because both are executable functions

```
wDrum.addEventListener('click', () => {alert("click!")})
```

or

```
wDrum.addEventListener('click', function () {alert("click!")})
```

further gotcha following code would trigger alert the moment JS engine reads the code, so we had to excapsulate it into a parent function.

```
wDrum.addEventListener('click', alert("click!"))
```

```js
var wDrum = document.querySelector(".w.drum");

wDrum.addEventListener('click', alert("click!"));

wDrum.addEventListener('mouseover', () => alert("hover!"));
```

```html
<button class=" another-class w drum some-other-class">w</button>
```

alert, console.log, or document.querySelector etc are self triggering functions they execute moment code is run and do not wait for your interaction unless they are scoped into a parent function which is triggered on call back through your interaction.

Comment: thanks for your answer that was quite explaining and teaching for me. @pavlindrom's answer consisted of a point to be changed however it did not give me the result I've been seeking, then I tried typing the arrow function from your solution in and there it worked. what was missing in this last version of my code I couldn't understand  though:                                                                                                                                   
     var wDrum = document.querySelector(".w.drum");

Comment: @canistrophedon I have provided an explainer to your query how the '.w .drum ' differ from '.w.drum'.....I hope it would give you better grasp going forward. in regards to0 arrow function I have given suplimentary explainer

Comment: @marc_s thank you very much for taking time to correct typos/mistakes in text. Highly appriciated.